# Escape second word in IF statement in Batch

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement

I've tried searching on Google, I've tried searching on StackOverflow, and I just can't find a simple way to escape the second word in an IF statement.

```
set /p operation=What would you like to do: 
IF %operation%==Copy files (
    rem code goes here
)
```

I know that it is because of the second word in the file, because if I delete the space inbetween "Copy" and "files", it works. The problem is, that is not natural, and it looks weird, so I just wanted to hear if there was a better way.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Before you say "enclose it in quotes", no, that doesn't work either.

Comment: There is no other way but using quotes: `if "%operation%"=="Copy files"`; the _space_ is a token separator unless it is in between `""`... for user input consider to do a case-insensitive comparison like `if /I`...

Comment: And if you insist on making the user type the whole command (instead of showing a menu of "A. Copy files", "B. Delete files" etc. and getting them to enter A, B or whatever), at least use `if /i` so they don't have to get the case exactly right.

Comment: quotes **do** work. Unless you use the wrong (typographical) quotes

Comment: I failed to understand the OP intention. As everyone mentioned, quotes indeed **do** work.

Comment: @tufda We've read the P.S. and enclosing it in quotes does work when done the way shown in the comment above and the answer below.  Did you perhaps use quotes differently when you wrote the P.S.? (E.g. did you only put quotes around `Copy files` and not `%operation%`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, which is mentioned by @aschipfl already. You need to put the quotes for both.

```
set /p operation=What would you like to do: 
IF "%operation%"=="Copy files" (
    rem code goes here
)
```

Comment: If you are looking for solution, this is it. Everyone mentioned it. I have tried it myself it does work. Maybe you could clarify more of what you are trying to achieve.